# RCC_AHB2PeriphClockCmd

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I'm beginner in Embedded programming. I'm programming in STM 32F407ZG. While programming the demo codes, i just came across the code 
**RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOF, ENABLE);** 
what is this?, explain it.

```embeddedC
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"

 void delay()
  {
   for(int i=0;i<0x3FF;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<0x3FF;j++);
  }

 void mx_pinout_config(void) 
  {
    GPIOG->ODR     = 0x00000000;    
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOF, ENABLE);
    GPIOF->MODER   = 0X55555555;                         // OUTPUT MODE SELECT 
    GPIOF->OTYPER  = 0x00000000;    
    GPIOF->PUPDR   = 0x00000000;
    GPIOF->OSPEEDR = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    GPIOF->ODR     = 0x00000000;       
  }   

 int main(void)
  {
    mx_pinout_config();
    while (1)
      {
        GPIOF->ODR = 0x0000000F;   
        delay();
        GPIOF->ODR = 0x00000000;   
        delay();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your code is trying to set GPIOG's Output Data Register, but doesn't enable the clock for GPIOG

Comment: What did you not understand about the reference manual from ST with respect to that register and that bit?

Comment: Output Data Register? The clock signal for a microcontroller remains same, I hope. Like in microcontroller 8051. But here how control clock signals for a specific pin.

Answer (score 1):

***STM32F407ZG*** is a ***low power device***.

In order to save power, the microcontroller is designed in such a way so that whenever any peripheral is required, then its respective ***bus clock needs to be enabled*** and then only the ***peripheral can be used***, and after ***the work of the peripheral is over*** then the ***clock must be disabled*** to save power.

In your case, you want to use `GPIOF` which resides on *ARM high-performance bus1* so `RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd()` enables/disables the clock of **AHB1** for `GPIOF`. **RCC** stands for ***reset and control circuitry*** and controls the clock of the CPU, microcontroller peripherals and various buses on it.